# How to get tag's name in php dom?

Tags: php, html, dom

I write a code to get the content . But this content may be a photo or a video . Can I get tag's name ?  My code:

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<img><iframe>');
```

if content is a photo , the output is :

```
$content = <img src="http://exxample.com" class="img-responsive">
```

if content is a video , the output is :

```
$content = <iframe src="http://exxample.com"></iframe>
```

I want to get :

img  or iframe

I tried to use getElementByTagName , but it need a parent tag to get child node .

Edit: I used this to get all content :

```
$content = Utilities::getContentBetween($html, "itemBody");

static function getContentBetween($html, $class)
{
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    $doc->loadHTML($html);
    $finder = new DomXPath($doc);
    $node = $finder->query("//div[@class='".$class."']");
    return $doc->saveHTML($node->item(0));
}
```

then I used this to get only img or iframe tags:

```
$content = strip_tags($content, '<img><iframe>');
```

Edit2:
if content is a video :

```
<div class="itemBody">
    <div class="clr"></div>
                    <meta property="og:image" content="http://img.youtube.com/vi/EfA0slJamjI/hqdefault.jpg"/>
        <span class="itemVideo">
    <div class="avPlayerWrapper avVideo">
        <div style="width:560px;" class="avPlayerContainer">
            <div id="AVPlayerID_7a182346_2039535915" class="avPlayerBlock">
                <iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/EfA0slJamjI?rel=0&amp;fs=1&amp;wmode=transparent" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen title="JoomlaWorks AllVideos Player"></iframe>                 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </span>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

If content is an image:

```
<div class="itemBody">
<div class="catItemImageBlock">
    <span class="catItemImage"> <a
        href="/item/29780-how-to-cook.html"
        title="How to cook?">
            <img src="/media/k2/items/cache/100f4197fe779a7a85aba6772f82c790_L.jpg"
            alt="how to cook?"
            class="img-responsive" /> </a> </span>
    <div class="clr"></div>
</div>
<div class="clr"></div>
<div class="clr"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your DOMDocument code?

Comment: Why are you making a string out of your fancy DOM object if you still need to parse more content?

Comment: oh , I want to check , if get img tag , i will insert to datbase value = photo , or if get iframe tag , it will insert with value = video

Comment: Can't you just query your dom for <img> and <iframe> resp.? As this seems what you actually want to know about..

Comment: I still don't understand :( . Can you give an example ?

Comment: What does your original `$html` look like?

Comment: it's all html structure of the page . then i used function getContentBetween to get the content inside <div class="itemBody"> (img or iframe tag inside here)

Comment: Please share the exact contents of `<div class="itemBody">`

Answer (score 0):

```
$img = $finder->getElementsByTagName('img');

$iframe= $finder->getElementsByTagName('iframe');
```

It can get specific tags. if you need to get the inner contents use `getAttribute()`.

LIKE `$iframe->getAttribute('src');`.